# Subspace of square matrices where all matrices are nilpotent and the products of the matrices are also in the subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

Let $A$ and $B$ be $3\times3$ square matrices (maybe could also examine $n\times n$) and let $U$ be a subspace where $A,B,AB\in U$. All matrices in $U$ are nilpotent. I conjecture that all matrices in the subspace either commute up to a constant ($AB=\alpha BA$), or they are all strictly upper (or all strictly lower) matrices.

My reasoning is this: if $A\in U$ and $B\in U$ are nilpotent and commute up to a constant, or are strictly upper (strictly lower) matrices, then $AB$ and $A+B$ will also be nilpotent. Now of course you could have matrices $A$ and $B$ that do not commute etc. but are such that $AB$ and $A+B$ are nilpotent. But the formulation of the subspace would need $ABA$, $AB^2$, $BAB$, $(A+B)A$, $AB+BA$ and infinitely more to be nilpotent. I just can't see how any $3 \times 3$ matrix (even $n \times n$) could be in the subspace without fulfilling my conjecture. Maybe there is an obvious proof of my conjecture, or maybe I am just wrong and their exists an obvious counter example, or maybe it is a hard problem. Either way I would love to get a response, thanks!

Edit: My knowledge in pure math (such as abstract algebra) is severly limited, nevertheless if there exists a proof using tools from such areas I would still appreciate it a lot!

Comment: "let $U$ be a subspace" do you mean a *subalgebra*? (i.e. closed not only by linear combinations but also by products)

Comment: @AnneBauval To be honest with you, I have not studied much pure math and therefore not really any abstract algebra. But I guess my answer is yes if I understand correctly. If $A, B \in U$ then we should have $cA, cB, A+B, AB\in U$, where $c$ is some constant.

Comment: Your hypothesis would look preferable if you said that each such subalgebra is similar to a triangular algebra.

Comment: @kabenyuk Sorry, I don't understand what that means since I have not studied abstract algebra (I am an early university student, and looking at this from an linear algebra point of view). Maybe I am not fully equipped to tackle such a problem, if not there exists a counter example (like Anne's if it is indeed correct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $U$ an algebra of $3\times3$ nilpotent matrices over some field $F$, there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}UP$ is a subspace of strictly upper triangular matrices.

Here is the proof. Suppose first that $U$ has a member $A$ of rank $2$. By a change of basis, we may assume that $A$ is the nilpotent Jordan block. Now let $B\in U$. By assumption,
$$
A^2B=\pmatrix{b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0},
\ AB=\pmatrix{b_{21}&b_{22}&b_{23}\\ b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}\\ 0&0&0}
\ \text{and}\ B=\pmatrix{b_{11}&b_{12}&b_{13}\\ b_{21}&b_{22}&b_{23}\\ b_{31}&b_{32}&b_{33}}
$$
are nilpotent. That $A^2B$ is nilpotent implies that $b_{31}=0$. In turn, that $AB$ is nilpotent implies that $b_{21}=b_{32}=0$. Consequently, since $B$ is nilpotent, we must also have $b_{11}=b_{22}=b_{33}=0$. Hence $B$ is strictly upper triangular.

Now suppose that all nonzero members of $U$ are rank-one nilpotent matrices. Let $A$ be a nonzero member of $U$. By a change of basis, we may assume that $A=e_1e_3^T$. Since $U$ is a subspace of rank-one matrices, either $U\subseteq\{e_1x^T:x\in F^3\}$ or $U\subseteq\{xe_3^T:x\in F^3\}$. In the former case, for an arbitrary $B=e_1x^T\in U$ to be nilpotent, $x_1$ must be zero. Hence $B$ is strictly upper triangular. Similarly, in the latter case, for $B=xe_3^T$ to be nilpotent, $x_3$ must be zero. Hence $B$ is strictly upper triangular.

Comment: I am not sure what this says about my conjecture. Sorry if I am missing the point.

Comment: (+1) Bigggie: it means that your conjecture is true: all your matrices commute up to a constant, because they are strictly upper triangular up to conjugation by some invertible matrix $P,$ and strictly upper triangular matrices commute up to a constant.

Comment: I see! Nice, this does not generalize to $n \times n$ though, right? Because I don't think $4 \times 4$ strictly upper triangular matrices commute up to a constant.

Comment: @Bigggie The result isn't true $n\ge4$. Let $\mathcal T$ be the subspace of all $4\times4$ strictly upper triangular matrices. Since it contains members that do not commute up to any constant, if $P$ is the permutation matrix for the transposition $(3,4)$, then $P\mathcal TP^{-1}$ contains matrices that are not strictly upper triangular and also matrices that do not commute up to any constant.

Comment: Thanks for the great answers! What if we remove the condition $AB \in U$, would the matrices still commute up to a constant? Essentially: if we have that $A$ and $B$ are nilpotent then for $\alpha A+ \beta B$ to be nilpotent for any constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ must we have that $A$ and $B$ commute up to a constant?

Comment: @Bigggie The counterexample in my previous comment still applies.